# How to authenticate with Foursquare OAuth2 within a jQueryMobile app (no useragent flow)

Tags: iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile app with jQueryMobile and I intend to deploy it onto iPhone thanks to PhoneGap.

My question is : how can I authenticate myself with Foursquare using the OAuth2 protocol in my jQueryMobile app ? One solution would be to use the useragent flow of OAuth2 but this would force the iPhone to launch Safari and thus not stay within the app. Are there any better solutions than this ?

Comment: but launching the mobile safari to enter the user credentials is a good way to get the trust of users.

Comment: I do agree with you but it's awful ergonomically speaking. Except if you know a way to automatically call back the application once authentified in Safari ? I know you can somehow do that with Obj-C native app but in JS... ?

Answer (score 1):

For an iPhone-based or client-side application like you would have in PhoneGap, 
Foursquare recommends one of these methods.

> - If you have no substantive server code, you can embed a web browser and use the token flow, redirecting the user to a dummy page on your domain. You can then grab the token off of the URL and close the browser. We have sample [Android](https://github.com/foursquare/android-oauth-example) and [iOS code](https://github.com/anoopr/core-data-talk/blob/master/example/Classes/FoursquareAuthViewController.m) for your reference.
> - If you have a server as part of your application, you can use the server flow above, possibly in an embedded browser. Similar to the Facebook API, you can add display=touch to your authorize or authenticate URLs to get a mobile optimized interface.
> - An alternative to the above is to use the server flow and an external browser, but redirect to a custom URI handler that brings the user back to our application. You can embed the secret in your application and exchange the provided code for an access token. PLEASE take steps to obfuscate your client secret if you include it in released code, and be prepared to rotate it if needed.
>
> https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

This could probably be handled with the ClientBrowser plugin for PhoneGap or just adapting the sample code they have provided into PhoneGap plugins.

Answer (score 0):

One of the core intentions of OAuth2 is to not allow browserless authentication flow like we did with XAuth in the past. Service providers want consumers to see what permissions they are signing off on, and want control of that process.

I'm not very experienced with Phonegap, as I'm a native developer, but if there's a way of instantiating a UIWebView and showing it to the user, you could at least keep the web interaction 'inside' of the application. Given phonegap is basically showing a  UIWebView this should be possible. It is possible to examine the source of the html within a UIWebView using

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```